# Bookdown stopped following chapter order specified in _bookdown.yml

Tags: r, bookdown

Bookdown will order chapters alphabetically unless [an order is specified after `rmd_files:` in the `_bookdown.yml` file](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/usage.html)

This has worked fine for me in the past but is not currently working.  Here is a MWE:

This [_bookdown.yml](https://github.com/jtr13/bookdown-start/blob/master/_bookdown.yml) specifies to render Chapter 2 before Chapter 1 and not include Chapter 3, yet Chapters 1, 2, and 3 are rendered in order in the [rendered book](https://jtr13.github.io/bookdown-start/). (Rendered with `bookdown::render_book("index.Rmd")`

The local preview has the same issue.

I am using the dev version of `bookdown` (0.10.1).

Any clues?

Comment: Sounds like I introduced a bug in v0.10... I'll look into it. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in **bookdown** v0.10, which [I just fixed](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/commit/6dd42819c2c5ff3cea02656ca932d063518646b3) on Github. You may try the development version:

```r
remotes::install_github('rstudio/bookdown')
```